# How do I express anonymous method override like in java with c++?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface d, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The above are very convenient to use,

what's the closest way to write it in c++?

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can only override `virtual` methods by definition.

C++11 introduces the `override` keyword, which alerts you in the same manner the Java equivalent does:

```
virtual void foo() override;
```

There's no such standard mechanism before C++11.

Comment: So I must define a class name each time I define a callback?

Comment: Well, what does it override otherwise?

Comment: See my demo above, I don't have to give another name at all in java

Comment: I think he asking about method override through anonymous inner class

Comment: @new_perl oooh I see, I though your were talking about the override annotation. In that case, for C++03 there's no way. In C++11 there might be, IDK.

Comment: @CyberDem0n yeah, I got that now :)

Comment: @Lyubomir Vasilev,seems there's no way to do method override through anonymous inner class.